# How to obtain ACLs for different sharepoint sites

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-rest-api

Using the graph API or sharepoint REST APIs, is there a way to obtain, for each site, the list of users/o365 groups that are allowed read access to the site?

We are able to obtain the list of sites using the graph API GET /sites?search=* but cannot find a way to get the list of users allowed to access each site (except for Sharepoint team sites associates with o365 groups that we can enumerate using GET /groups/{group-id}/sites API call.

We are building a server side application so need to do this from the server using application-level permissions, and not from the client.

Pointers for how to do this are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like there is no such ebdpoint that gets the site permissions and there are few uservoices [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?query=get%20permissions%20to%20site) that are close to your scenario. Please upvote them so that it could be developed by the product team in future

Comment: Moving this to Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no such endpoint that gets the site permissions and there are few uservoices [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?query=get%20permissions%20to%20site) that are close to your scenario. Please upvote them so that it could be developed by the product team in future.

Comment: There is none appropriate. I added a uservoice for this - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/42129535-graph-api-to-fetch-the-permissions-for-a-sharepoin

Comment: Hi is there a SOAP API that returns this info?